# Comments disappeared with no cause for deletion - why?

Tags: support, comments

#### Problem

A bunch of my own comments (OP) and some from someone else all disappeared recently from the [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/247206/will-query-continue-to-run-even-after-network-times-out).

**I know that moderators can delete comments, but in this case I do not believe they would have.**

I asked a supplemental question in the comments of the accepted answer to which the poster replied.  My comment is now gone and the answer to the comment remains.

Why would this comment have been deleted or, if it wasn't, where did it go?

Comment: I saw the answer was edited to add more information. While I don't know what your comment was about, I can only assume that the answerer responded with adding the information to the answer (which is the correct approach) and flagged the comments as "no longer needed".

Comment: You have two different questions here, so it's difficult to decide what to do with your question. I've moved it to DBA meta because you seem to want closure on this specific event and that's something the DBA mods are better suited to offer. The FR has come up several times [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105338/shouldnt-i-be-notified-if-the-community-moderators-flag-delete-a-comment-of-min) so leaving this on MSE as a FR would just lead to it being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Some of the moderators on DBA.SE are extremely allergic to comments and need to carry epi-pens in case of exposure. Therefore posts on this network are inoculated against the less-productive comment strains and flare-ups are aggressively excised.

Comment: Do you see those comments in your profile? (`Profile |> All actions |> Comments`) I just noticed that comments have vanished from [an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/247415/15356) to a question I asked. I had stated that I cannot change the database structure...

Comment: @hot2use I don't see any evidence of any comments on that question or any of its answers.

Comment: @hot2use No I do not see them in that section.  I think they get entirely deleted

Comment: @AaronBertrand Strange. Thanks for looking.